# How to listen on subdomain with toxiproxy?

Tags: tcp, proxy, network-programming

I'm using [toxiproxy](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy) with an api call. I don't have total control on what the api uses as the final hostname. The api uses `foo.bar` as hostname. I can control `bar`, but I cannot control `foo`.

The normal usage of toxiproxy is to listen on e.g. `localhost:1234`.

Is there anyway I can tell toxiproxy to listen on `foo.localhost:1234`? I'm getting "`error=listen tcp: lookup foo.localhost: no such host`"

Comment: Your infrastructure detail is still not bit clear. Listening to `foo.localhost` and if `foo.localhost` is `127.0.0.1` then how it would make a difference?

Comment: Did you have a chance to try out my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your solution won't work as your system would try to resolve `foo.localhost` which indeed doesn't exist.

The idea is slightly different - 
you need to trick the app by mapping the hostname it uses to `localhost` via `/etc/hosts`.
In your case it would look as follows:

1. Lookup the real ip address of foo.bar i.e. `host foo.bar`
2. Go to /etc/hosts and add a line `127.0.0.1 foo.bar` (more [details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html))
3. Run a `toxiproxy` so that in listens on `127.0.0.1` and forwards requests to the original ip address from p.1
4. As a result the app's requests would go via `toxiproxy` as expected